# Is it a good practice to implement artificial delays in programs?

Tags: language-agnostic, while-loop, delay

I've noticed that, every time a program relies on a `while` loop to keep it open, it uses almost 100% of the CPU. Adding a delay of 20ms puts that number down to 0%.

The following code would max the CPU:

```
while(executing){
    // Do some things
    if(Quit) executing = 0;
}
```

But the next wouldn't:

```
while(executing){
    // Do some things        
    if(Quit) executing = 0;
    delayFunction(20); //20ms delay
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? If so, what would be considered an adequate delay?

Are there better ways to avoid overloading the CPU?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Performance analyst's number one answer is, "It depends."](http://zvm40for40.blogspot.com/2012/07/it-depends-and-with-linux-it-depends.html)**  There are lots of factors to consider, some making voluntary `yield()` or `delay()` look good, some making them look bad.

- What kind of machine and task are we talking about? (Loops using the radio can cause phones to get very hot.)
- How important is the task at hand? (Cardiac monitors **must** capture and display samples on schedule.)
- What else is the machine doing? (VM hosts run lots of guest machines, CPU loops starve other processes.)
- Will supervisory code preempt the task? (Most OSes will let higher priority tasks take over in mid-loop.)

Answer (score 1):

A sheduler on the OS level take care of ditributing CPU ressources and time across processes.

Without the delay, the computer try to run the loop as fast as possible, so it use all ressources available for this process.

With a delay, you tell the sheduler that he has X msec to do other things. If no other process need processing time, then the CPU does nothing for this delay.

This is lot an issue, it's a feature. And there is no better way do to that. All the magic reside in the number of msec to wait. But it depends on many factors so it's impossible to be specific about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different concept between those two "delay techniques". In the first place, what you do it's just spinning the CPU, your program actually runs on the CPU in those moments and consumes a lot of resources.

On the other hand, in the second case you can imagine that your program is put on hold for 20ms, and the CPU can do something else in the meantime (or just stay idle). What happens in background is more or less a [sleep system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28system_call%29).

In general, you'll want to go with the second approach because it's much less CPU consuming.

Comment: The first example doesn't have any delay, that's the issue. I would like to know if it is common practice to add a delay in a loop that keeps the program open, so it won't max the CPU while doing nothing.

Comment: It's not a common practice due to the obvious fact that it's very CPU consuming. But it's _a_ way of adding delay to your program flow. Let's say you want a delay of 20 ms, that add a for loop from 1 to 100k, with no instruction inside and there you go, you've artificially created a small delay.

Answer (score 0):

What you can achieve with delay is longer time of you program execution.
Operating system is responsible for CPU sharing between process.
As long as you don't change you process priority to realtime and thread priority to Highest, you should not worry about delays

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons for inserting deliberate delays.  I once worked on the early stages of populating a very large database.  While it was still small the response was lightning fast, but was obviously expected to get slower as more and more data was added to the database.  In order to keep the users expectations realistic we set a minimum response time at the start so the users would not see the slowing response.  Anything that came back in less than 0.5 second was held until that minimum time had elapsed and only then sent on to the user.